# Pandas: How to refer to the row value while replacing a value

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is to replace a value based on the row value.
But I couldn't figure out how to do it. Code is like below.

```
def get_new_value_b(db, value_a):
    # Take a value_a and return value_b
    ...


a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
df.loc[df["value_a"] in a_list, "value_b"] = get_new_value_b(db,df["value_a"])
```

What I want to do here is to replace a `value_a` if the value exists in `a_list`
But on the condition, there is an error.

> Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Also if the condition is True, I want to get a new value by passing the `value_a` to a function (`get_new_value_b`)
but seems like it also refers to the entire column, not the specific value in the row.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df.loc[df["value_a"].isin( a_list), "value_b"] = df["value_a"].apply(get_new_value_b)
```

Better is call function only for matched rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value_a":  ["a" ,"b" ,"d" ,"f","c" ]})

def get_new_value_b(value_a):
    # Take a value_a and return value_b    
    return '_' + value_a

a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
m = df["value_a"].isin( a_list)
df.loc[m, "value_b"] = df.loc[m, "value_a"].apply(get_new_value_b)
print (df)
  value_a value_b
0       a      _a
1       b      _b
2       d     NaN
3       f     NaN
4       c      _c
```

EDIT: If need pass multiple parameters use lambda function:

```
m = df["value_a"].isin( a_list)
df.loc[m, "value_b"] = df.loc[m, "value_a"].apply(lambda x: get_new_value_b(df1, x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but looks like the second issue remains.. `get_new_value_b` function misses  the parameter in this way.

Comment: @Ooto - can you add some sample function `get_new_value_b` to question? input is one scalar value? Or something else?

Comment: @Ooto - in my solution is passed value from `value_a` column like scalar

Comment: @Ooto - solution should working well, what mean `get_new_value_b function misses the parameter in this way.` ?

Comment: @Ooto - hmmm, what parameter? value_a ?

Comment: The function misses the parameter.  ```TypeError: get_new_value_b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value_a'```

Comment: @Ooto - added sample data, seems not understand each other.

Comment: Really sorry. I was dumb my real code is a bit different.. The function takes two parameters actually.. that's why the error happened.. (The first parameter is not related to data frame)

Comment: @Ooto - so use instead `].apply(get_new_value_b)` - `].apply(lambda x: get_new_value_b(df1, x))`

Comment: Really appreciate.. You saved my day. My code works as I wanted.